# Unsure about step in dervation of Arnoldi iteration (from Fundamentals of Numerical Computation)

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

Although I (think I) understand theorem [8.4.2](https://tobydriscoll.net/fnc-julia/krylov/subspace.html#theorem-subspace-krylovmult) in the description of [Krylov spaces](https://tobydriscoll.net/fnc-julia/krylov/subspace.html#krylov-subspaces)
in chapter 8 of Fundamentals of Numerical Computation, I don't quite get how the author makes the jump to [equation 8.4.3](https://tobydriscoll.net/fnc-julia/krylov/subspace.html#equation-arnoldivec).

In other words, how does

$$
{\bf Ax} = c_1 {\bf Au} + c_2 {\bf A}^2{\bf u} + \ldots + c_m {\bf A}^m{\bf u} \in \mathcal{K}_{m+1}
$$

imply that

$$
{\bf Aq}_m = H_{1m} {\bf q}_1 + H_{2m} {\bf q}_2 + \ldots + H_{m + 1,m} {\bf q}_{m+1}
$$

I am aware that $H_{ij}$ is the Hessenberg matrix but no mention of it has yet been made.

Comment: For anyone struggling with the basics of Krylov spaces and GMRES. I wholeheartedly recommend chapter 4 of [Fundamentals of Numerical Mathematics for Physicists and Engineers](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=9JbiDwAAQBAJ) by Alvaro Meseguer. It is a absolutely wonderful text.

Answer (score 2):

Since $q_{1},\ldots,q_{m}$ span the same Krylov space as $b,Ab,\ldots,A^{m-1}b$, it follows that $Aq_m$ lies in the next Krylov space. We want $q_{m+1}$ to orthonormally extend the basis to that space as well. So $Aq_m$ must be a linear combination of $q_1,\ldots, q_{m+1}$, which is all that ($8.4.3$) is saying. In fact, that is the origin of the upper Hessenberg structure.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Are they in the same space because because $q_1, \ldots, q_m$ because is derived from the Gram–Schmidt orthonormalization of $b, Ab, \ldots, A^{m-1}b$?

Comment: @Olumide, I was making an inductive argument to show how to go from m vectors to m+1 of them. Technically this is orthogonalization but not the classical  Gram-Schmidt process. It's closer to the so-called modified Gram-Schmidt algorithm.